# MyISAM Foreign Key like functionality

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `TABLE1` which have 5 columns that I rarely use and design-wise should be separated from that table. Therefore, I created a new table called `TABLE-REF` where its primary key (called `refID`) is actually the ID of the corresponded columns in TABLE1. That way I separated these 5 columns from my main table. I did not use a foreign key since I am using MyISAM.

On the rare occasions when I do need to select these 5 columns for rows in TABLE1, what will be the most efficient way to select them?

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE-REF WHERE refID={$table1ID}
```

Beside indexing the column `refID`, is there any other improvement I can make to improve the complexity of the query?

Comment: Are there any other where clauses?

Comment: Nope.. I have the TABLE1 ID in my hand, just need to fetch the corresponded row from TABLE-REF (i.e. refID={$id_from_table1} )

Comment: Then leave it as it is. As mysql anyway gonna fetch all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both rows as one if you use a join. so no more back to the database for each row in TABLE to get the TABLE-REF row.

```
SELECT 
    T.*, R.* 
FROM `TABLE` T 
INNER JOIN `TABLE-REF` R ON R.refID = T.ID
WHERE <your conditions>
```